# What is the right approach to deploying a production server?

Tags: php, mysql, deployment

I am developing a server application that is mostly used to registered users and gives services upon request.

It was built from scratch, and I am not fundamentally a PHP developer.

I must say that this is the first time I am deploying a production to the web.
The end of phase 1 is drawing near and I would like to know what do you think is the best approach to deploying this server.

- How do I debug on a production server ? how do I log all my actions to log files ?
- How should I handle the resources and traffic? how would I know if the server is reaching its limits ?

Any approaches to evening out the load ? I have one DB, is it possible to let another server use the same DB to take off the load from the first one ?
(Of course these are general and long shot questions, but I'd like to have a bigger picture of what I am doing here)

Is there anything I should know about security measures other than my own code ? like if I can trace down a hacking attempt for example?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking all these basic question, then you should not be deploying a production server. But needless to say, you are.

It's usually never a good idea to debug on a Production server, that is what QA or Development or Testing servers are for. If you are deploying a combination of Apache, PHP, MySQL, usually for PHP, there is a php_error.log file for you to look at. The location of that is base on your httpd.conf

Handling resource traffic is based on your volume, you have to answer that question yourself. Google MySQL configuration optimization and you'll find many helpful tips to correctly configure and optimize it's speed, and when you hit your limit, you'll know.

Security, that is another very vague question, security differ base on your needs, such as a bank vs a mom and pop website. I guess research network secure, and always keep in mine this, don't over kill, security is good enough when it accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you shouldn't debug on a production server, all testing should have been completed in your development environment.  However, of course you should thoroughly test everything once it is on the production server and fix any issues that may appear.  By making sure your development environment is as close as possible to the live one in terms of settings etc you can mitigate the risks but you can never totally eradicate any potential issues.

Depending on your server you can try running a command such as "top" or "topaz" at the command line, this works on a Unix box if it has the correct installation and will tell you how much CPU is free and how much is being used.  This would give a rough idea if it can handle the traffic you are throwing at it.  Handling traffic and managing resources is a huge area in itself, there's a lot that can be done such as load balancing for example if you have multiple servers, you may find VMWare is helpful here also.  There are also call-gapping techniques that can be employed depdending on what your application is for and who is using it.  And yes you can have one database shared between more than one server.

There is professional monitoring sofware you can buy to show how busy your servers are that may help, just search for "monitoring software" for example.

Security is another huge area and the solutions would depend on what you are deploying and who is going to use it.  You should be aware of all the likely methods of attack that your application is likely to be subjected to and have planned your code to cope with this, for example SQL injection, session hijacking etc.

You need contingency plans in case hackers compromise your site and ideally disaster recovery plans as well, depending on how critical your application is.

Best advice is to plan everything thoroughly before you start and get your bosses to approve the plans to cover yourself.

If you have more precise questions I can give more precise answers, I used to work for a global bank and have experience of releasing critical code to production servers with all the red-tape that goes with that

;-)